# How to find and replace certain keywords in a specific column of a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, text-mining

I want to find some specific keywords in a specific column of a data frame and replace them with other keywords that already exists in that column. For example technology (freq=2) with technologies (freq=3).
I need to do this without changing the rest of the columns in the data frame and save it in the same column in the same data  frame. In this way I can have 5 keywords of "technologies".
However, I have  no clue how to start doing this in rstudio specially because I have to keep the output as a data frame. Can you please guide me where to begin with?

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you're using, not the IDE.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say this is your data:

```
dat <- data.frame(C1=c("Hi", "My", "Example", "Hi"), 
                  C2=c("This", "Is", "An", "Example"), 
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

You can use `gsub` to replace all occurrences of a value in one columns like this:

```
dat$C1 <- gsub(pattern="Example", replacement="NEW", dat$C1)
```

You can go through all columns like this:

```
lapply(a, gsub, pattern="Hi", replacement="NEW")
```

Does that do what you are after?

Comment: You could use the stringr package from the tidyverse and use the "str_replace" or "str_replace_all" functions - they also look for a pattern, and then replace it with something you want - you may also want to look into REGEX as that could save you some time when trying to find the correct pattern!!!!

Comment: thanks! they look useful. regex kills me though, i find it so confusing :P

Comment: good link for regex is this: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/machine-learning/advanced-techniques/regular-expressions-string-manipulation-r/tutorial/

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much.

Comment: An additional question... What if I have a random keyword like " Hi randomword" that I don't know what is the randomword expression, so I want to cut it from the random phrase but keep the "Hi"?

Comment: And what if I have "Hi (Hi)"?

Comment: If it's always in brackets you can `gsub("(Hi)", "(NEW)", vector)` and that will only replace what's in the brackets

Comment: No, some are in the brackets, some are not.

Comment: Weel you can just run the command twice, once with brackets once without. You need to do the bracketed one first though